# NetBeans GUI designer is not showing components

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-designer

I have installed netbeans 12.0. After I opened the project GUI design is not showing. Please refer below image.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Netbeans?

Comment: What is Login.java ? How did you create it ? Did you check Netbeans log file ?

Comment: Version 12 of netbeans